# Precision of logarithmic mesh

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to draw a nice three-dimensional diagram using PGFplots. Its Z axis should be logarithmic. Unfortunately when the values get to small, the precision isn't enough to get a smooth curve.
Hope this MWE is ok...

Thanks for your tips.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={140}{20},
        grid=major,
%
        xlabel style={sloped},
        xlabel={Bildschirmdiagonale $h$},
        x dir=reverse,
%       
        ylabel style={sloped},
        ylabel={Entfernung $d$},
%
        zlabel={Raumwinkel $\Omega$},
        zmode=log,
    ]
        \addplot3[
            mesh,
            domain=20:60,
            y domain=2:20,
        ] { 4*pi/180*atan( ((12*x)*(22*x)) / (2*1000*y*sqrt(4*(1000*y)^2+(22*x)^2+(12*x)^2)) ) };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What sometimes helps is to analytically manipulate the expressions. All I did was to divide numerator and denominator by 10, such that the `(1000*y)^2` in the square root becomes `(100*y)^2`. This yields

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={140}{20},
        grid=major,
%
        xlabel style={sloped},
        xlabel={Bildschirmdiagonale $h$},
        x dir=reverse,
%       
        ylabel style={sloped},
        ylabel={Entfernung $d$},
%
        zlabel={Raumwinkel $\Omega$},
        zmode=log,
    ]
        \addplot3[
            mesh,
            domain=20:60,
            y domain=2:20,
        ] {0.1* 4*pi/180*atan( ((12*x)*(22*x)) /
        (2*1000*y*sqrt(4*(100*y)^2+(2.2*x)^2+(1.2*x)^2)) ) };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see the wiggles are gone. And one may go on using this until one is fine with the outcome.